# QGIS 3x rotated label shifts direction without the reason

Tags: qgis

Could annyone help me with this problem.
I want to have number 22 in the same alignment as 23 is. Unfortunately when I hit 90 degree of rotation it shifts without the reason.
What is the reason behind it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.
We have to set the Show upside-down labels "When rotation defined" as follows:

[image]